# Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Xamarin.iOS"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I checked out the perfectly working xamarin forms project to my mac and tried building from VS mac. But I get the below error:
" /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Xamarin.iOS". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. (MSB3245) (Assette) "
I tried deleting bin and obj folders, tried unloading and reloading projects but the issue still exists. But when I create a new Xamarin.Forms project from VS it perfectly builds and runs without any error. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can check whether the path of the default project folder opened by visual studio is normal. If some NuGet packages are used in your project, you can try to reinstall the package to see if it works.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT You mean "Show in finder" on the portable project? Yes it is normal.
I think it is a problem with Xamarin.iOS sdk reference but I compared with the newly created project which builds and runs. I couldn't find any difference

Comment: You can check whether some NuGet packages used in your project need to be updated. You can check this GitHub issue([Visual Studio for Mac. Could not locate the assembly "Xamarin.iOS"... #10191](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10191)) to see if it inspires you.